# How can we retrieve HTTP headers for a URL opened through Selenide?

Tags: java, selenide

I'm trying to retrieve HTTP headers for a URL opened through Selenide

```
 @Test
    public void test() {
        String url = "https://contoso.com/somepage";
        open(url);
        //I can pull the cookies but how can I pull the HTTP headers?
        Set<Cookie> cookies = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().manage().getCookies();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe webdriver still don't have that.
You may use another library like Jsoup https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url